# Can someone help explain the use of keras.backend.learning_phase_scope(1)?

Tags: keras, tf.keras

Need help as I am new to Keras and was reading on dropout and how using dropout can have an impact on loss calculation during training and validation phase. This is because dropout is only present at training time and not validation time, so comparing two losses can be misleading.

Question is

1. The use of learning_phase_scope(1)
2. how does it impact validation
3. What steps to do to correct for testing loss when dropout is used?

Answer (score 2):

It's not only `Dropout` but `BatchNormalization` as well that need to be changed or it'll affect validation performance.

If you use keras and just want to get validation loss (and or accuracy or other metrics) then you better use `model.evaluate()` or add `validation_data` while `model.fit` and don't do anything with `learning_phase_scope`.

The `learning_phase_scope(1)` means it's for training, 0 is for predict/validate.

Personally I use `learning_phase_scope` only when I want to train something that not end with simply `model.fit` (visualize CNN filter) but only once so far in past 3 years.

Comment: No sure if I am following this correctly, you say have only used this once in 3 yrs, and in all the code examples in see online no one uses it too. Then how is the model compensating for penalization of the training loss due to drop out? Because if we do not compensate validation for dropout (say 0.5) then each nuron will get the input signal twice as large as the network was trained on. Leading the two losses train and valid not compareable.